# UDP multiple socket

Tags: java, sockets, udp

everyone. I have a question on socket use. It seems pretty simple though, but i am not being able to manage it. So the question sounds: Can I use only one socket to send data packets to multiple clients??

```
ds1 = new DatagramSocket();
dp1 = new DatagramPacket(packet, packet.length, InetAddress.getByName(address1), port);
dpto2 = new DatagramPacket(packet, packet.length, InetAddress.getByName(address2), port);
dpto3 = new DatagramPacket(packet, packet.length, InetAddress.getByName(address3), port);**
```

Address1, address2 and address3 are different here. I want to connect to multiple clients in one program run and send UDP packets to them. I haven't tested it yet, just want to get some suggestions on how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: The same packet to multiple clients (broadcast) or different datagrams to each client?

Comment: The same packets to several destinations

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't connect to clients with UDP, UDP is connectionless.  If you actually need the concept of connection you need to switch to TCP (but in many cases you don't actually need that notion).
2. Yes you can send data to multiple clients using one `DatagramSocket`

Comment: @fvi, when i create a Datagram Packet i specify an IP address field, so the packets get sent to all ip addresses. Is there a way to list ip addresses in command line interface (as arguments for run) and create packet automatically for every address entered???

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I understood the question, If the data to send is the same for all clients then there is no need to create separate packets for each client, just create one packet and change its address (and port if necessary)
Something like this would do it:

```
/**
 * Send a DatagramPacket to all addresses in hosts.
 * @param socket 
 *  A created DatagramSocket
 * @param hosts 
 *  Array of strings containing the hosts to send the packet, 
 *  each one can be either a host name or a dotted IP address.
 * @param port
 *  The port the clients are listening
 * @param data
 *  Data to send
 * @return
 *  Number of packets sent.
 */
int sendPackets(DatagramSocket socket, String[] hosts, int port, byte[] data)
{
    if (hosts.length > 0)
    try
    {
        int ret=0;
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        packet.setPort(port);
        for (int i = 0; i < hosts.length; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                packet.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hosts[i]));
                socket.send(packet);
                ret++;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                Log.e("SEND:", "Error sending to host: " + hosts[i]);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can use that function like this:

```
try {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] data = "This is a test message.\n".getBytes();
    sendPackets(socket, new String[] { "192.168.1.10", "192.168.1.12", "192.168.1.54" }, 2020, data);
} 
catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: Alright, I will try to use your code and will respond you. Thanks a lot anyway, that gives some insight.